# How to transfer touchesEnded to a UIView added by touchesBegan on a different UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm using the `touchesBegan` method in my main UIView to create a second UIView and add it as a subView.  What I'd like to be able to do is to have the second UIView get the `touchesEnded` event when I lift my finger up.  I don't seem to be able to do this - the original UIView that I tapped always receives the `touchesEnded` event.

**Edit:**  the reason I have to find some way to "transfer" the `touchesEnded` is that the initial `touchesBegan` is received by a UIView that is removed as a subView at the same time the new UIView is added, so the `touchesEnded` actually fires immediately as the subView is removed.

Answer (score 2):

Hm what I would do is the following:

```
- touchesEnded
{
   if( yourViewIsThereAsSubView )
   {
     // pass on the event to the other view
     [yourSubView touchesEnded];
     return;
   }
   // normal behaviour
   [super touchesEnded];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have the new UIView get the touchesEnded event.  You'll probably have to resort to getting the location of a touch in the touchesEnded event, then ask the parent view which subview contains that location.